# The structure of “with them came”

Tags: grammar, meaning

> China experienced a burst of intellectual creativity: its classical texts date from this period, and **with them came the formulation of some of China’s oldest moral and religious precepts.**

I found it difficult to understand the bolded line and I want to know the structure and grammatical rules of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little bit of a stretch because the parallelism is not perfect between "its texts date" (present) and "with them came" (past). The reader has to infer an appropriate verb, a synonym of "date", that can be a parallel for "came". For example:

> Its classical texts appeared in this period, and with them came the formulation...

Hopefully the structure is clearer now. It's a common (narrative) inversion of this straightforward sentence:

> Its classical texts appeared in this period, and the formulation ... came with them.

The reason for the inversion is that "the formulation" begins a long noun phrase that would otherwise create a wide separation before "came with them", making it hard to resolve the pronoun.

Comment: Thanks! But what do you mean by "resolve the pronoun"? Can you give me an example?